# Is "Flip by" an idiom? What does that mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

In a work chat someone (a native person) wrote this:

> Flip by the Android Community meetup at 12:15pm today to hear about my
> explorations into different types of Android animations

But I can not find anywhere on the internet that can define `Flip by` to match this context. Does it really have a special meaning? Can someone show me it in a dictionary that defines this word?

Comment: The normal expression to use is 'drop by'. D and F are next to each other on the keyboard, and so are I and O, so it is possible that the writer got one of those letters wrong, and 'auto-correct' decided to go for 'flip'.

Answer (score 2):

While it *might* be an auto-correct error,  I note that it is about "android animations", and so I suspect word-play.  A flip book is a type of animation made from paper, and "flip" suggests, in a playful way, a single frame of an animation, and so a very short visit.

It's not a regular idiom. If it's not an auto-correct error, then it's something that the writer made up, probably playing with the "animation" theme.